# Invalid number when converting a date to another format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle19c

I have this query, and i am trying to format all dates for the two columns mentioned in the query below to the format mentioned:

```
SELECT
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(timeone,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI PM'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MIPM'), 
    TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(timetwo,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI PM'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MIPM')
FROM
    my_date_table
WHERE daywork = '28-MAY-2021';
```

and i want to convert the results from timeone and timetwo to another date format `DD-MM-YYYY HH:MIPM` but when I run the query I got back invalid number. The datatype of the timeone and timetwo columns in my table are date

When i run the query without the formatting, the results are:

[image]

Where did i go wrong?. All alternatives and solutions are welcomed

Comment: Dates are stored using an internal format, so it is unclear what you are trying to.  You seem to just want to convert the date to a string.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, i am just trying to change the format of the results in the picture so the the query is what i was using to try change the format to my desired format.  so the image with the results is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS but i want it to be DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI PM

Comment: What data type(s) are your timeone and timetwo columns? If they are strings then (a) that's not a good idea and (b) you just have your `to_date()` and `to_char()` the wrong way round.

Comment: As you can see above, i mentioned that the datatypes are dates

Comment: Seems like you just need `to_char(timeone, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI PM')`. This converts the Oracle DATE value into a string in the format `'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI PM'`. Alternatively, since you tagged Oracle SQL Developer, you can go into the NLS section of the preferences and set that as your display format for dates.

Comment: @AlexPoole suggestion worked

Comment: but when i tried @WilliamRobertson method, i got the invalid number.

Comment: @BasudevSingh - then they are not real dates, they are string representations of dates. Check the actual column definition in `usr_tab_columns`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The datatype of the timeone and timetwo columns in my table are date

The error says that isn't the case; they seem to be strings. As a date this would work:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP '2021-05-28 07:34:00' AS DATE),'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI PM')
FROM
    dual

TO_CHAR(CAST(TIMESTAMP'2021-05-2807:34:00'ASDATE),'YYYY-MM-DDHH:MIPM')
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-05-28 07:34 AM
```

but as a string it would get the error you see:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR('2021-05-28 07:34:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI PM')
FROM
    dual

ORA-01722: invalid number
```

So, you are really trying to convert one string representation of a date to a differently-formatted string representation. To do that you need the inner function call to be `to_date()`, and the outer function call to be `to_char()` - you have yours the wrong way around:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(timeone,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MIPM') as convertedone, 
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(timetwo,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MIPM') as convertedtwo
FROM
    my_date_table
WHERE daywork = date '2021-05-28'

CONVERTEDONE       CONVERTEDTWO
------------------ ------------------
28-05-2021 07:34AM 28-05-2021 03:30PM
28-05-2021 07:04AM 28-05-2021 07:04AM
```

The format model for the `to-date()` call also has to match the actual string value, so I've changed that to `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'`. And `'28-MAY-2021'` is also a string not a date, so - assuming that really is a date field - I've changed that to a date literal. You could also use a `to_date()` on that string value, but it's easier with a literal (and if you supply a month name then you should specify the date language too).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ab99ac025fc7390201ff95acb64215e4).